# React Site not deploying properly

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I am looking for guidance on a React deployment. I have made a portfolio and have done everything as per the guidelines. Even after multiple repeated tries I am still getting the same error.

Final Result

Only the text "Portfolio"

**Package.json:**

```json
{
    "homepage": "https://raghav3155.github.io/portfolio",
    "name": "portfolio",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.44.3",
        "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
    }
}
```

Tried multiple times and checked all the steps. Deployed and redeployed. No result!

Tried deploying multiple times. Still getting the same output. Only the text "Portfolio" and not the actual site.